# Split words using VBA in Excel cells

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to split a string with tokens separated ‘;’ into 2 list of values.
For example I have the string:
AXX1.CYY1;AXX2.CYY2;AXX3.CYY3;AXX4.CYY4
I would like list it to be separated into 2 lists, the first should contain values on the right of ‘.’ whereas the second should have values on the left
Practically, the outcome should be:

```
AXX1;AXX2;AXX3;AXX4
CYY1;CYY2;CYY3;CYY4
```

So far I think my strategy is create a loop in a VBA function that splits the words. The single value is in turn split into 2 portions which are put in a list.
Further to this how do you apply the code to excel cells.
If there is any other method to accomplish it is welcome.

Comment: did you try **Googling** this?

Comment: Are these strings always this same length? Do the values for the 1st list always start with `A`, and the others `C`?

Comment: Do you mean separating a string into 2 *lists* of strings or separating a string into 2 strings? You seem to mean the latter, but you said the former. Also, by `AXX1;AXX2; AXX3.;AXX4` do you mean `AXX1;AXX2; AXX3;AXX4`?

Comment: So, the string is starting out in one cell and ending up in 2 (one above the other), correct?

Comment: Thanks Karl. You perfectly understood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic logic makes sense. It can be implemented like thus:

```
Function ChopandSplice(s As String) As Variant
    Dim chunks As Variant, first As Variant, second As Variant
    Dim temp As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    chunks = Split(s, ";")
    ReDim first(0 To UBound(chunks))
    ReDim second(0 To UBound(chunks))
    For i = 0 To UBound(chunks)
        temp = Split(chunks(i), ".")
        first(i) = temp(0)
        second(i) = temp(1)
    Next i
    ChopandSplice = Array(Join(first, ";"), Join(second, ";"))
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim v As Variant
    v = ChopandSplice("AXX1.CYY1;AXX2.CYY2;AXX3.CYY3;AXX4.CYY4")
    Range("A1") = v(0)
    Range("B1") = v(1)
End Sub
```

Running the test sub leads to:

[image]

Comment: The situation is good. I would try it and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a non-VBA solution, this assumes your string is in cell A1.

Place in cell B1:

```
=LEFT(A1,4)&MID(A1,FIND(";",A1,1),5)&MID(A1,FIND(";",A1,11),5)&MID(A1,FIND(";",A1,21),5)
```

Place in cell C1:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1,1)+1,4)&MID(A1,FIND(".",A1,11),5)&MID(A1,FIND(".",A1,21),5)&MID(A1,FIND(".",A1,31);5),".",";")
```